# php xpath query on imported xsd

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xsd

I have two .xsd files. In the main xsd (`main.xsd`) I import a second xsd (`foo.xsd`), so I can use types that are defined there. See example:

```
file:main.xsd
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
        attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:foo="Foo"
        >
    <xs:import schemaLocation="foo.xsd" namespace="Foo" />

    <xs:complexType name="someType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="Foo:anElementType" name="someElement" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>    


file:foo.xsd
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
        targetNamespace="Foo"
        attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="anElement" type="anElementType" />

    <xs:complexType name="anElementType">
        <xs:attribute name="yesOrNo" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

How can I do an Xpath query on main.xsd that will return the attributes of `anElementType` in `foo.xsd`. 
Currently, I load `main.xsd` and hoped that DOMXPath would know of the import, but that does not work. I have Googled for an hour, and did not find more suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run an xpath query against one XML file and expect it to return results from a completely different XML file, unless you believe in magic and pixies.

Comment: Ok, thank you. In my ignorance I was hoping that the `<xs:import` would indeed do some kind of magic, especially since there is a `schemaLocation` attribute. But alas. Will accept the answer and throw in a bonus `+1` for the magic and pixies ;-)

Comment: Pixies are always +1 ;)